# Multiple kafka producer setup: Eliminate delayed/stale writes

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a central database from which reader reads the data in order it is received and then writes to a Kafka Topic. For resiliency, we have multiple readers but at a time only one should be active and hence, events are written in Kafka in the order in which they are received. This switching of readers is decided by the central database to which they are subscribed and if the reader hasn't responded in last n seconds, it can switch to a different reader to maintain SLA.

For simplicity, say each change is essentially a document change. So, change1 updates Doc1, change2 updates Doc2, change3 updates Doc1 again etc and as part of each change, you receive the updated document.

Now consider the following scenario. In the example below, Dx-Vy represents DocX-VersionY:

1. **Reader1 becomes the active reader.**
2. Reader1 receives D1-V1, D2-V1 and commits to Kafka. D1-V1, D2-V1 commit acked to Database.
3. Reader1 now receives D1-V2, D2-V2 but **froze before committing to Kafka**
4. **Database makes Reader2 as the active reader**. And because it never received the ack from Reader1, it will provide the same update to Reader2.
5. Now, Reader2 receives D1-V2, D2-V2 and commits to Kafka. D1-V2, D2-V2 commit acked to Database.
6. Reader2 receives D1-V3, D2-V3 and commits to Kafka. D1-V3, D2-V3 commit acked to Database.
7. **Reader1 comes back and writes D1-V1, D2-V1 (which is stale data now)**.

Now, we have stale data committed to Kafka. I want to avoid this scenario.

I could not find any documentation that says Kafka Producers have a concept of lease where only if the producer has the lease, it can write to the Kafka Topic (or partition). Or any concept of Etags where it can only change the document if somekind of Etag match succeeds (whether it is at partition level, event key-level etc). I am still new to Kafka, so this might be a naive question and the scenario can be avoided using Kafka correctly. Can someone point me in the right direction or to the correct documentation (if it exists) to avoid something like above from happening?

I went through Kafka documentation but couldn't find any Kafka attribute that can help me with this scenario. I also Google-ed similar problems to see if there is any existing answer for such a problem.

Comment: Look up Distributed Sagas

Comment: @cricket_007 I don't think this applies here because the Reader that is writing changes to Kafka can get stuck for a long enough time and meanwhile, we need to start committing changes from another reader. Since the original producer is stuck, we can't communicate it to stop writing into Kafka. Also, the other readers can't wait for too long for ack from the original reader due to tight SLAs. I am thinking if there is a way to block a Producer from writing to Kafka using some Kafka cluster configuration? That way before switching to the new reader, we block the original producer first.

Comment: There is no way to block a producer... What do you mean it gets stuck?

Comment: Producer can get stuck by say the machine/process writing into Kafka gets hung and then recovers later. During the window when the machine/process is hung, there is no way to communicate with it and hence, stop it from committing to Kafka on recovery (if say the machine/process gets hung just before writing to Kafka).

Comment: Still not clear how it gets stuck (IO wait? Threads dying? Long GC times? ... these should be addressed outside the context of Kafka problems). Sounds like you need some external monitoring system that sets up a distributed lock and prevents other things from happening if you must wait on that producer to do something